# vertical align div with dynamically body height and width

Tags: html, css

I have a div, with fixed width and height, fixed on the screen.

I want to align this vertically on the middle, but the body will change the height, as the resolution of the screen changes, its a full screen layout, the height and the width will change as the screen resolution of the viewer decrease or increase.

Basically I have.

```html
<div id="center">
    <ul id="wrap">
        <li><a href="#">In&iacute;cio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Historico</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Comissao Organizadora</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!--menu-->
```

And I had tried using `margin-top:50%, margin-bottom:50%` but no success.

Comment: Please update your tried code. In the above code there is no div tag like you mentioned

Comment: Do you want the div to be centered on the page regardless of document/page width?

Comment: post some of your code please, it is better if it is in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Try this `#center { position: fixed; width: 500px; height: 500px; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin: -250px 0 0 -250px; }` margins are always the half of the width/height value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c46Zr/) demo

```
<div id="center">
    <ul id="wrap">
        <li><a href="#">In&iacute;cio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Historico</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Comissao Organizadora</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS Style

```
html, body, #center {
    height: 100%;
    position:relative;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
#center #wrap {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left:40%;
}
```